# Python Pyserial - Threading

Tags: python, multithreading, pyserial

Python 2.7

This is the code I have. Could you please tell me whats wrong. This is the beast I could come up with after studying threading for over two days continuously.

The serial communications work when I dont use threading.

```
import threading
import time
import sys
import serial
import os
import time

    def Task1(ser):

    while 1:

        print "Inside Thread 1"
        ser.write('\x5A\x03\x02\x02\x02\x09') # Byte ArrayTo Control a MicroProcessing Unit
        b = ser.read(7)
        print b.encode('hex')
        print "Thread 1 still going on"
        time.sleep(1)


def Task2(ser):

    print "Inside Thread 2"
    print "I stopped Task 1 to start and execute Thread 2"
    ser.write('x5A\x03\x02\x08\x02\x0F')
    c = ser.read(7)
    print c.encode('hex')
    print "Thread 2 complete"


def Main():
    ser = serial.Serial(3, 11520)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = Task1, args=[ser])
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = Task2, args=[ser])
    print "Starting Thread 1"
    t1.start()
    print "Starting Thread 2"
    t2.start()

    print "=== exiting ==="

    ser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not properly syncing the threads. I suggest putting the `ser` object into the global namespace and using a lock, mutex or semaphore to prevent the two threads from accessing the single `ser` object at the same time.

Python Module of the Week explains it best [here](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/#controlling-access-to-resources)

Comment: I looked at the lock you suggested. Say t1 acquires lock, it will have it for ever as it is a while loop - there is no way to unlock it. Any ideas on how to go around it? t1 - is a long processing event whe at the same time other events like t2 happen

Comment: A lock can be acquired and RELEASED. If you get the lock before using ser and release it after, it ill let plenty of time (e.g. during sleep of task 1) to other tasks to use ser.

Comment: @Julien This is the error I got:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/kundemj/Desktop/Production GUI/Trial python Codes/test19.py", line 15, in Task1
    b = ser.read(7)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 252, in read
    raise SerialException('call to ClearCommError failed')
SerialException: call to ClearCommError failed

Answer (score 0):

Example for using lock

```
import threading
import time
import sys
import serial
import os
import time

def Task1(lck,ser):

    while 1:

        print "Inside Thread 1"
        lck.acquire()
        ser.write('\x5A\x03\x02\x02\x02\x09') # Byte ArrayTo Control a MicroProcessing Unit
        b = ser.read(7)
        lck.release()
        print b.encode('hex')
        print "Thread 1 still going on"
        time.sleep(1)


def Task2(lck,ser):

    print "Inside Thread 2"
    print "I stopped Task 1 to start and execute Thread 2"
    lck.acquire()
    ser.write('x5A\x03\x02\x08\x02\x0F')
    c = ser.read(7)
    lck.release()
    print c.encode('hex')
    print "Thread 2 complete"


def Main():
    ser = serial.Serial(3, 11520)
    lck = threading.Lock()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = Task1, args=[ser,lck])
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = Task2, args=[ser,lck])
    print "Starting Thread 1"
    t1.start()
    print "Starting Thread 2"
    t2.start()

    print "=== exiting ==="

    ser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Main()
```

Comment: This is the error I got: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner self.run() File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs) File "C:/Users/kundemj/Desktop/Production GUI/Trial python Codes/test19.py", line 15, in Task1 b = ser.read(7) File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 252, in read raise SerialException('call to ClearCommError failed') SerialException: call to ClearCommError failed